# How to build a JAXB model to match my XML?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I need process this XML with JAXB, but I am not sure how to create an object model to match it.

```
<UI5SOLTGET>
    <Form  FrmName="U5_SolTar" FrmTit="Solicitud de VOUCHER" >
        <FormItems  FrmIte="1" FrmLab="Numero de Serie" FrmVal="" FrmData="SER" FrmType="T3" FrmRest="" FrmEna="true" />
        <FormItems  FrmIte="2" FrmLab="Numero de Voucher" FrmVal="" FrmData="VOU" FrmType="N9" FrmRest="" FrmEna="true" />
        <FormItems  FrmIte="3" FrmLab="Fecha Vencimiento" FrmVal="" FrmData="FECP" FrmType="F" FrmRest="!" FrmEna="true" />
        <FormItems  FrmIte="4" FrmLab="Es XNET" FrmVal="" FrmData="XNET" FrmType="B" FrmRest="" FrmEna="true" />
        <FormItems  FrmIte="5" FrmLab="Numero de Trajeta" FrmVal="" FrmData="TAR" FrmType="T20" FrmRest="" FrmEna="true" />
        <FormItems  FrmIte="6" FrmLab="Plan de la Tarjeta" FrmVal="" FrmData="PLAN" FrmType="N3" FrmRest="" FrmEna="true" />
        <FormItems  FrmIte="7" FrmLab="Numero de Cartera" FrmVal="" FrmData="CAR" FrmType="N3" FrmRest="" FrmEna="true" />
        <FormItems  FrmIte="8" FrmLab="Numero de Autorizacion" FrmVal="" FrmData="DT1" FrmType="T12" FrmRest="" FrmEna="true" />
        <FormItems  FrmIte="9" FrmLab="Numero de Lote" FrmVal="" FrmData="DT2" FrmType="T12" FrmRest="" FrmEna="true" />
        <FormItems  FrmIte="10" FrmLab="Numero de Ticket" FrmVal="" FrmData="DT3" FrmType="T12" FrmRest="" FrmEna="true" />
        <FormItems  FrmIte="11" FrmLab="VISA Itau  [C]red/[D]eb." FrmVal="" FrmData="CRDB" FrmType="T1" FrmRest="C|D" FrmEna="true" />
    </Form>
</UI5SOLTGET>
```

Comment: what you are actually looking for?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! You need to give a bit more information - what you've tried, what you expected to get out, what didn't work etc.

Comment: Your XML should should starts with something like this <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?> if you are going to use JAXB for parsing. Use this basic tutorial and build your code http://www.mkyong.com/java/jaxb-hello-world-example/

Comment: Check this tutorial: http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/02/jaxb-tutorial-getting-started.html

Comment: Sorry ... I dont speak english very well and its dificult for me explain the problem.

Comment: @joserosende Post your code in this case...

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far, we could help you with that

Comment: Thanks Stephan, im reading that ink

Comment: I could parse xml with a single element and some attributes, but in this case I have a "Form" element and several elements "Items" I do not understand how to create the class

Comment: @KalaiarasanManimaran XML declaration is not required for JAXB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Java Model

For your use case you will need:

1. A `FormItems` class.  This class appears to have all its data mapped to XML attributes so you will make use of `@XmlAttribute` on each of the mapped properties.
2. Their are many `FormItems` elements so they will be referenced by a collection.  The parent element contains mapped data so you won't be able to leverage the `@XmlElementWrapper` annotation and will need a `Form` class that had a `List<FormItems>` property.
3. You will also need a class that corresponds to your root element annotated with `@XmlRootElement`.

### Mapping Your Java Model

Once you have your Java model your need to adjust its metadata to make sure it matches the XML you want to read/write.  The easiest way to do this is to populate your object model and marshal it and make note of where it differs from your target XML.  JAXB doesn't require any annotations so you can start doing this right away.

Since all your XML elements and attributes start with capital letters you are going to find you need to leverage the `name` property on all uses of `@XmlRootElement`, `@XmlElement`, and `@XmlAttribute`.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, its very clear ... I'll try to do this in the afternoon, thanks a lot